# Can this be done with a query (MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

PHP and MySQL

This is an existing project with a poor design and table layout.. that has been requested to have a new 'feature' added.

I'm wondering if a query like this can be put together (not the greatest with query stuff)

Quick Summary:

A form post is made.

- table it gets a messageid and a (blank) subid

if a NEW post is made.. the above happens again..

- (messageid and a (blank) subid)

if a 'comment' to an existing post is made..

- table it gets a messageid and a subid that matches the 'parent' post/thread it is making a comment on

Unfortunately this is all in the same table.. and seems like it would have been better served in a multiple table layout or something?

But:

- I know the parent posts (because the subid col is empty)
- I know the child posts (because the subid col has value matching the parent post is a comment to)
- All posts have a timestamp.

How can I get a query, and group/order things like:

- Select -parent posts- without subid
- immediately have all -child/comment posts- under this

And have it (initially?) order by the parent post_date then child/comment post (sub order by their post_dates)

Here is an example table set-up:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19dae/2/0

Not sure if a simple GROUP BY is needed here?  Or a more advanced sub-select needs to be done?

The order needs to be 'first' done by parent post 'post_date'..  and (somehow) get the next child/comment posts to be -injected- after their 'parent' post in the query/array return..

Here  is my desired outcome order:

Desired outcome:

```
'2020-03-30 09:48:50', 'Poster A', '49203-30032020094850000000', ''
'2020-03-30 09:50:50', 'Poster B', '49204-30032020095050000000', '49203-30032020094850000000'
'2020-04-03 09:55:50', 'Poster C', '49205-03042020095550000000', '49203-30032020094850000000'
'2020-03-31 09:48:50', 'Poster C', '49205-31032020094850000000', ''
'2020-04-03 09:40:50', 'Poster B', '49204-03042020094050000000', '49206-010432020094850000000'
'2020-04-01 09:48:50', 'Poster D', '49206-010432020094850000000', ''
'2020-04-02 09:49:50', 'Poster E', '49207-02042020094950000000', ''
```

### update:

Addressing: @Ngo Van Quan

For his answer.

This:

```
select * from testtable
order by
(
 CASE testtable.subid WHEN 0 
 THEN testtable.messageid*1000 
 ELSE testtable.subid*1000 + testtable.messageid END
), 
testtable.messageid;
```

(which I think it what you intended to supply instead of what you posted??)

** does nothing

Answer (score 0):

This query won't give you exactly what you're looking for, but will give you at least one row for every post. If there are no comments, you'll get one row with a bunch pf null info for comments. If there are comments you'll get one row per comment with the parent post information repeated:

```
SELECT * 
FROM testtable AS post 
LEFT JOIN testtable as `comment` ON `comment`.subid = post.messageid
WHERE post.subid = ''
ORDER BY post.postdate ASC;
```

Comment: but another 'parent' post could be made before (and after other possible sequential) comments are made on a previous parent post.

Comment: I corrected the query according to your example table. It's not exactly want you want, but I don't think you can get something interleaved like that. This is will at least give you the information in a reasonable format.

Answer (score -1):

Here is sql to do your tasks:

`select * from table  order by (CASE table.subid when 0 then table.id*1000 ELSE table.subid*1000+table.id END), table.id;`

Comment: what is bustrip?  this doesnt compile.  why the lone " double quotes? syntax errors too?

Comment: No- I had fixed it and posted it at bottom of original post above... also testedon SQLFiddle...  -does not work-

Comment: Hi @whispers I understand why its not working for your case, the message_id and subid must be an integer to guarantee the calculation